# Throwing exceptions from Linq Query exception

Tags: c#, linq, exception

lets say I have an input string I need to format into a list of `KeyValuePair<string,float>` entries. The format of the input string is

```
key:value;key:value;...
```

lets say I have this Linq code to do it

```
var orr = from pco in (overrrides ?? string.Empty).Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
          let pair = pco.Split(new char[] { ':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
          select new KeyValuePair<string, float>(pair[0], float.Parse(pair[1]));
```

Now, if the input string is not properly formated the linq will fail on two possible points, index out of range on `pair[]` and format exception on `float.Parse`. Both of these exceptions will bobble up and mean absolutely nothing to the caller.

I know I have two workarounds (not use linq and loop like its 1990s or grab above exceptions and repackage), however I was wondering if I can somehow inject validation steps into linq query itself to throw my own exceptions if I detect an anomaly (`pair.length<2` or `pair[1]` not a number)?

Comment: pair.length wont be any problem - you can use a where clause. For float.Parse you can try some construction with TryParse, but in this case you should consider breaking the linq into linq+foreach parts for the sake of readability ;)

Comment: @J.Steen, right, sorry, corrected.

Comment: No worries, just wouldn't want people focusing on typos. =) (like I did!) ;)

Comment: Do you just want to throw an exception on the *first* failure, or collect *all* failures?

Comment: @Grumbler85, wont fly, the where will simply skip over invalid entries, I want it to blow up to the caller. The reason is that this is part of price override code, its all or nothing and missformatted string indicate an error in callers code so I have to assume other entries are invalid as well.

Comment: Maybe it makes sence to write your own extension method, where you would make your validation steps and throw your own exceptions?

Comment: @JonSkeet, blow up on first. I'll just send the ArgumentException with "invalid price override list format".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what I thought of doing is impossible since `throw`, as statement, cannot be used in expression lambda. The only way is to create an external function with side-effect and run it through the `let` or `where` statement that will apply it to every entry.

```
var pairIsValidOrDie = new Func<string[], bool>(pair => {
    float amt;
    if (pair.Length != 2 || !float.TryParse(pair[1], out amt)) throw new ArgumentException("ERROR: invalid price override string);
    return true;
});

var orr = from pco in (overrrides ?? string.Empty).Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
          let pair = pco.Split(new char[] { ':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
          where pairIsValidOrDie(pair)
          select new KeyValuePair<string, float>(pair[0], float.Parse(pair[1]));
```

Answer (score 3):

One simple option is to change it to:

```
// I don't think I'd use ?? like this, but that's not the point of the question.
var unparsed = (overrrides ?? string.Empty).Split(new char[] { ';' }, 
                                                  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var parsed = unparsed.Select(x => ParsePair(x));

...

static KeyValuePair<string, float> ParsePair(string text)
{
    // Note that you could be more efficient using IndexOf/Substring
    string[] bits = text.Split(new char[] { ':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    if (bits.Length != 2)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Value should be a colon-separated key/float pair");
    }
    float value;
    if (!float.TryParse(bits[1], out value))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Cannot parse " + bits[1] + " as a float");
    }
    return new KeyValuePair<string, float>(bits[0], value);
}
```

You're still using LINQ for the "sequence" part - you're just breaking the "how to handle a single value" part into a separate method. (You *could* do it as a big statement lambda, but I wouldn't.) Note that by doing so, you could test the `ParsePair` method independently.

(You might get away with just `.Select(ParsePair)`, depending on which version of C# you're using. Method group conversions and type inference aren't the best of friends though.)

Comment: ok, this works and is actually just the payload of a custom foreach loop. I was actually looking for a way to embed exception throwing into query language. Not just for this problem, but for future reference as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could test the string first with a regular expression

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"^((\w:\d);)*$");
bool test = r.IsMatch(tosplit);
```